# How to obtain a feed of comments entered through the 'chat' box during a YouTube live broadcast?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

The YouTube API enables users to obtain a comments feed, e.g. via `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments?orderby=published`.

However, when I try to do just that with the video ID of a live stream, the result is always empty, no matter how many comments have been submitted. The only difference between a live video and any other video (or recording of a live stream) is that the 'comments' section is replaced with a 'chat' box, whose comments seem not to be available via the API.

When the stream is stopped, all comments submitted through the chat box 'disappear' entirely and can no longer be accessed. However, all comments submitted after the live broadcast has been archived (i.e. the recording has been made available) show up in the comments feed.

For a real-time application I need to access the 'chat' comments while the broadcast is still live, to retrieve user-submitted questions.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: For a short time, you can use https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=VID_ID&embed_domain=www.example.com It works for a while, but next day they were gone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is now possible to return chat messages for **your own broadcasts** using the [`LiveChatMessages`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages) endpoint as part of the YouTube Live Streaming API.

When creating a new `liveBroadcast` object, a `liveChatId` String will be returned as part of that `liveBroadcast`'s `snippet`.  Pass your broadcast's chat ID to `LiveChatMessages/list` endpoint's `liveChatId` parameter, and `id`, `snippet`, and `authorDetails` into the `part` parameter.

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId={liveChatId}&part=id%2C+snippet%2C+authorDetails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This will return an array of [`liveChatMessage`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages) resources.  The actual chat message is contained in the `textMessageDetails` dictionary as the value for the `messageText` key.

```
"textMessageDetails": {
  "messageText": string
}
```

Comment: Could you Please Give a C# method for this??

Comment: @DarkPh03n1X what are you having trouble with?  The web request?  Maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: Why aren't all broadcasts available? Threre are no private broadcasts, right?

Comment: Five years have past since the answer was posted. The situation changed? Do we still have to stick to Selenium to fetch chats of someone else's live stream?

Answer (score 4):

[Ibrahim Ulukaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973552/ibrahim-ulukaya), a member of Google's Developer Relations team focusing on the YouTube API, stated the following on a similar quesiton ([How to get chat content of Youtube live event in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418455/how-to-get-chat-content-of-live-event-youtube-in-java)):

> The API doesn't have connection to live chat at this moment. We are
>   hoping to get that content incorporated into API soon.

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/26427743/1085891

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Note this is using Selenium, this was posted before youtube's api supported it, rather look at the other answers for better support**

I came up with a basic script for this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Starting();
        }

        public void Starting()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yu5Om0SH3No");
            
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            //Find Comments
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("comment-text"));
            Console.WriteLine("Text: " + element.Text);

            //Find User names
            IWebElement element2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='g-hovercard yt-uix-sessionlink yt-user-name']"));
            Console.WriteLine("Username: " + element2.Text);

            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Will need more hours of work to make it read the page as the comments flow.

Comment: Why Are You Writing In Sentence Case Like Jaden Smith?

Comment: But seriously, this is really not the best method of doing this. It's slow, it's very likely to break when they change any markup, it won't get all comments, only those visible, etc.

Comment: I actually did this using google's api. when google's api supported it a couple a months ago.As For Your First Question I Have No Idea What You Are Talking About.