# How to get chat content of Youtube live event in Java

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How do I get the chat content of a Youtube live event in Java? (not the comment of a normal video)

Answer (score 2):

The API doesn't have connection to live chat at this moment. We are hoping to get that content incorporated into API soon.

Comment: Thank Ibrahim, please help me another problem. when add a live event, i want to set a privacy that only people that specified by list of emails can access . how to do that?

Comment: @KunDark that's not possible.  The privacy of live events is treated the same way as regular YouTube videos.  You could make your live event `unlisted` and send the link out to a certain number of emails.

Comment: @Ibrahim Ulukaya, any timeline one when this content will be available via the API?

Comment: This seems like a pretty severe missing feature - I can't imagine anyone would use live chat without this. I won't ever again!

Comment: API's live chat feature is in the works. I'll update once it's available for testing.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya Is this still the case? It's been nearly a year since this question was answered :(

Comment: We have an API for it in testing stage for now. We hope to have it open eventually.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya Is it still on testing stage? :)

Comment: It is now possible to get the chat messages from **your own broadcast** using the YouTube API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34438176/2415822