# youtube live chat api

Tags: youtube, chat, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to obtain youtube live chat messages from live broadcasts.

According to [How to get chat content of Youtube live event in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418455/how-to-get-chat-content-of-youtube-live-event-in-java/26427743#26427743) the API did not support it in October, 2014. And I can't find anything in current youtube API.

Does anyone know when this will be supported in API? And perhaps is there a not documented way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found a dirty way to get messages.

I just need to load a broadcast page source and implement its java script until messages are loaded. And then parse them out of DOM. This can be done for example with the help of http://www.seleniumhq.org/ project.