# How do I use LiveBroadcasts:list from YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to use YouTube API for Live Broadcasts. But, I don't get any results. Here's what I do:

1. Go to #Live YouTube channel:

   ```
   www youtube com channel / UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig
   ```
2. Open any Live Broadcast to get Broadcast ID (for example, "CGt1Ac1gEZc").
3. Try to use this Broadcast ID in irb:

   ```
   irb(main):038:0> list = youtube.list_live_broadcasts("id,snippet,contentDetails,status", id: "CGt1Ac1gEZc")
   => #<Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::ListLiveBroadcastsResponse:0x0000000546a960 @etag="\"oqbvhYxBE6fAbRk6m7aLlHf5s1I/P7sEkFelJCqPWY-5t7EUKYER_MQ\"", @items=[], @kind="youtube#liveBroadcastListResponse", @page_info=#<Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::PageInfo:0x000000054634d0 @results_per_page=5, @total_results=0>>
   irb(main):039:0> list.items.inspect
   => "[]"
   ```
4. As you see, the `@items` array is empty.
5. Open https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list to try to get data there, but still nothing (see image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl4Bx.png

Still, empty `@items` array.
Even though this broadcast is 100% online, I tried filtering by "all" broadcasts, the result is the same: no items found.

Is this my fault or something happened to YouTube API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That query is returning 0 items because the [`liveBroadcasts/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) endpoint can only be used for broadcasts that the channel your are authenticated as has created.  You cannot use the `list` endpoint to retrieve information about anyone else's broadcast.

If you want to retrieve information on another channel's broadcast, you have to use the standard [`Search/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint.  This will return return only live events from a particular channel, without being authenticated as that channel/user, if you know that channel's `channelId`:

`part -> snippet`

`channelId` -> `[channelId of the channel/user with the live event]`

`eventType -> live`

`type -> video` (required when setting `eventType` to `live`)

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Thank you!

Though, it doesn't provide the liveChatId, which is crucial for my main goal: I want to get messages from the Chat of the Live Broadcast channel.

So ,the next question is: can I use the `liveChatMessages/list` endpoint to retrieve the messages from NOT my broadcast chat?

Comment: @Ohforf there is currently no API exposed for retrieving chat messages on another channel's broadcast.  For related discussion, and the API to retrieve chat messages from **your own broadcasts**, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26229728/2415822

Comment: OK, great. Thank you very much!

Comment: I wanted something similar for getting the uptime of a stream. Seems it's not possible only using `search`.

Comment: Aww that's great, Its a big relief. Google has been ruining my time with https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

For getting `liveStreamingDetails` that contains (scheduledStartTime/activeLiveChatId) for upcoming streams you'd need to perform

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&channelId={YOUR_CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=upcoming&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And then take out `response.items[0].id.videoId` and use it for

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I think you can do for live events as well with `eventType=live` in the first request