# Copy and save YouTube Live Chats in csv or xlsx format

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I would like to copy and save the content of YouTube Live Chats in a csv or xlsx format.  I have downloaded the example file ListLiveChatMessages.java, but do not know what to do with it.  (I am also wary of Java, and would prefer not to have to install it on my Mac OS Sierra MacBookPro.

Comment: Hi, your question as it is now is off-topic for Stack Overflow and will be closed unless you edit it with more information. Please show us exactly what you have tried by posting you code and explain what didn't work or what error messages you got.

Comment: I apologize for the "off-topic" nature of the question for Stack Overflow.  I am asking it here only because this is the forum that Google directs one to for questions about the YouTube API:  "Google engineers monitor and answer questions about the Google API Explorer on Stack Overflow using the tag google-apis-explorer.

To get help, submit your questions to Stack Overflow with the google-apis-explorer tag. Be sure to also tag your question with the tag for the API you are querying using the API Explorer."

Comment: I would expect Ibrahim Ulukaya, or someone in a similar capacity at Google, to address my question - preferably with more information than was provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229728/how-to-obtain-a-feed-of-comments-entered-through-the-chat-box-during-a-youtube?rq=1.